# Fill a ShapeRenderer rectangle with an image(.png)?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to libgdx. I am trying to write a basic android game with the libgdx framework

Is it possible at all to fill a rectangle drawn with libgdx ShapeRenderer with a given image?

If yes, how, and if no, is there any kind of hack or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images to be put on the screen in Libgdx (and OpenGL) are known as "textures".  The `ShapeRenderer` library does not support textures.

That said, the Libgdx texture and `SpriteBatch` APIs are optimized for drawing image rectangles.  Check out the overview and tutorial here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-textureregions%2C-and-sprite